# pyqt6-tools installation error caused by pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pyqt6, pyproject.toml

my python version is 3.12, and my pip version is the latest.

when i install pyqt6-tools, an error occured. the information is below.

```
 × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
```

how can i do with this error, it stop me from studying pyqt6

succeed in installing pyqt6-tools because i want to use qt designer

Comment: I had similar problem using python 3.12 but after downgrading to python 3.10, installation worked fine